# Movement using a Rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, rigid-bodies

I've been using the transform property for movement so far and that left my Physics a little choppy on collision. To counter this I switched movement using Rigidbody.velocity. This is a sample of my code.

```
//Start
rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
jumpForce = 5;
//Update
horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("HorizontalInput");
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, 0.0f);
rb.velocity = movement * speed;
```

this worked when it came to left and right, however when I want to jump I use this function and my character does not move, is there something wrong I'm doing or am I too much of a beginner to understand?

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
   rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're overriding the velocity when you do horizontal movement so the jump velocity has no effect. You should use `rb.AddForce()` for horizontal movement too.

You have to be careful not to add too much force though. For an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72805337/1134902).

Answer (score 0):

`Vector3.up` is the same as `new Vector3(0f, 1, 0f)` and since X and Z axis are **0** => your character will not move when jumping.

You need to save existing X and Z velocity in rb.velocity without any changing them when jumping:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    Vector3 velocity = rb.velocity;
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(velocity.x, jumpForce, velocity.z);

}
```

Since you change velocity instantly - you'll get instant velocity change which is the same as using `AddForce` with `ForceMode.Impulse`